# Svg image in an img tag shows a border

Tags: image, svg

I have the following code

```
.clsName {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  // background-color: #0057bf;
  background-image: url('svg/ico-plus-add.svg');
  color: transparent;
}
```

Now I want to display this in a clickable link, I use the following for that

```
<a (click)="method()" href="#">
   <img class="clsName" />
</a>
```

The problem is that I get a border around the image, how do I get rid of this, and as a side note what is the best way to show an .svg image that is clickable?

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS class add `border: 0;`